# SQLite Database Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using an SQLite database to save workout information.  After I made an update my database stopped working, I could no longer view any saved data from the database.  After trying to fix it for a while I reverted to an old commit before any changes to the database were made and cleared the data and cache from the app and ran the old version on my device but now even that old version - which I know worked fine before - is unable to save any databases to the phone.  Not sure what the problem could possibly be but I would appreciate any help.

Heres the code from my database:

```
public class WorkoutDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "workouts2.db";
    public static final String TABLE_WORKOUTS = "workouts2";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_WORKOUTNAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_EXERCISENAMES = "exercises";

    public WorkoutDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WORKOUTS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_WORKOUTNAME + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_DATE + "INTEGER" +
                COLUMN_EXERCISENAMES + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS " + TABLE_WORKOUTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add a new workout to the database
    public void addWorkout(Workout workout){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_WORKOUTNAME,workout.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EXERCISENAMES,workout.exerciseNamesToString());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE,workout.getDate().getTime());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_WORKOUTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    //Removes a workout with the name workoutName from the database
    public void deleteWorkout(String workoutName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_WORKOUTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_WORKOUTNAME + "='" + workoutName + "';");
        db.close();
    }

    //Returns a list of the users workouts that are stored in the database
    public ArrayList<Workout> getWorkouts(){
        ArrayList<Workout> workoutList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WORKOUTS + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_WORKOUTNAME))!=null){
                String workoutName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_WORKOUTNAME));
                String exerciseNames = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXERCISENAMES));
                Date workoutDate = new Date(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DATE)));

                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(exerciseNames.split(",")));
                workoutList.add(new Workout(workoutName, workoutDate, list));
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return workoutList;
    }

    //Returns the number of rows in the exercise table
    public int numWorkouts(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_WORKOUTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in the database creation script in `onCreate` method

More specifically this line:

```
COLUMN_DATE + "INTEGER" +
```

Should be:

```
 COLUMN_DATE + " INTEGER, " +
```

Notice the space before `INTEGER` and the comma `,` after it.

**EDIT**
You have to uninstall and reinstall the app again to make changes have effect.

Comment: ... or increase your DATABASE_VERSION constant value.